# How to create a simple API in Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I have never worked on the backend and never created an API, all I know is to handle the JSON response, [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-put) doesn't help much, but I do not understand "PUT - Writing Data".

However, I just want to know that how can I create a simple dictionary of multiple arrays or key-values as rest API, So that it can be fetched and i can show the data in table view etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Firebase Documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write), if you wanna create a node on Firebase realtime database, you can simply set a value to any key you want. The value here should be NSDictionary.

This is the code you can refer to:

```
// create a new node
[[[_ref child:@"users"] child:user.uid] setValue:@{@"username": username}];

// you can also use update to create a new node
NSString *key = [[_ref child:@"posts"] childByAutoId].key;
NSDictionary *post = @{@"uid": userID,
                   @"author": username,
                   @"title": title,
                   @"body": body};
NSDictionary *childUpdates = @{[@"/posts/" stringByAppendingString:key]: post,
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/user-posts/%@/%@/", userID, key]: post};
[_ref updateChildValues:childUpdates];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wanted to know if i can do it on website and mobile user can fetch json

Comment: sure you can! you can find more in the documentation that I attached above.